# How to remove part of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string `btnHome`. How can I remove `btn` and only get `Home` from it in javascript / jQuery?

I used slice like `str.slice(3, -1)` but it gives me `Hom` whereas I need `Home`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-1` part (just use `str.slice(3)`).

The `-1` argument says *slice to 1 character from the end of the string*.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
alert(str.slice(3));
```

Need not to give `-1` there.So it will slice it from `starting` of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to do it:

```
str.split('btn')[1]; // Home
```

```
str.slice(3); // Home
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use substr() method:

```
  target.substr(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pKeya/1/)

```
  var txt="btnHome";
  txt.slice(3,txt.length)
```

By using substring

```
 txt.substring(3,txt.length);
```